# Pagination in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to display the matching  tweets .lets say for example the matching results has 50 records, I need to display 10 records per page.I am getting the output which has all results but when I use pagination its showing link to different pages , but when I click the link to next page it says  "string not matched". I tried different combinations like 5 per page ,but when I click the link to the next page it says "string not matched", but when I try without pagination it shows all the results

My  code for the  controller

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]

    search_term[" "] = "%"
@tweets = Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE? ", "%#{search_term}%").paginate( page:  params[:page], per_page: 3)
```

My code for the view

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>


<ul>



  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

Anyone please help me with this

Comment: What is your error message and trace exactly?

Comment: It says "string not matched" . the  trace goes to this line     app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:7:in `[]='
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:7:in `index'

Comment: What do you want to do in `search_term[" "] = "%"` line? This seems to be the source of your problem.

Comment: It should replce blank space with  percentage symbol "%", its used as a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in

```
search_term[" "] = "%"
```

line. If it should replace whitespace with "%", it should be:

```
search_term.gsub!(/\s/, '%')
```